authjs running on NextJs using wrong port on localhost
I am using authjs with email link authorisation.
After submitting the email address I get the below error message:
GET /api/auth/signin? callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F 200 in 13ms

[auth][error] Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:25
I am running nextJs on localhost:3000
In .env.local I have:
AUTH_TRUST=false
AUTH_SECRET="Cebtyp-5qexve-mogvas"

# AUTH_URL=http:localhost:3000
NEXTAUTH_URL=http:localhost:3000

I have tried with AUTH_URL but this still does not work:
The versions I am using are:
"next": "^14.2.18",
"next-auth": "5.0.0-beta.25",
Please assist in the steps necessary to get the callback on port 3000.
